# How to connect to a nib from within StoryBoard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have some code ([ILColorPicker](https://github.com/jawngee/ILColorPicker)) that I want to install into my iPad app, which is using StoryBoards.  The instructions from the author say:

- In your view controller's XIB, add a UIView and then set it's class to ILColorPickerView
- Wire the delegate property of the ILColorPickerView to your view controller in Interface Builder by selecting the UIView and clicking on the last tab.  Then click on the circle next to "delegate" and drag that to "File's Owner" on the left.
- Implement the delegate method:   colorPicked:(UIColor *)color forPicker:(ILColorPickerView *)picker

How do I do this, when I am using Storyboards and there is no delegate or "File's Owner"?  I have created a class with a subview to hold the picker, but see now that I don't need the subview.  With that in mind, how do I connect this to my controller's view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files Owner is the View Controller.  You don't need a Nib file for this, you can use a scene with a ViewController and just follow the directions from there.  You can add a class (of type UIViewController) to you app and then associate that class with the VC in storyboard.  That class will be the "Files Owner".

Comment: So, is there any way to get it into the subview?  That way I could position it exactly where I want it...

Comment: Just drag a UIView into the ViewController view?

Comment: It already has a UIView... right now, I'm trying to connect the "delegate" to the "File's Owner" (the UIView), but there is NO "delegate" to connect to.  What do I do now?

Comment: Connect the delegate to the ViewController that contains that view and include the delegate methods in it.

Comment: I tried to connect the delegate as you said, but I am getting a build error on the @synthesize delegate, pickerLayout, color; statement in ILColorPicker.m.  The error is: 

"Existing ivar 'delegate' for property 'delegate' with  assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained"

What does that mean? and how do I fix it? (I assume the author of the code wrote it using XCode3.x, if that helps.)

Comment: No, when I say connect the delegate, that just means to select the object in the VC (in IB) and then open the connections inspector and drag from the delegate to the VC.

Comment: Now I'm getting the same error in two views in the IL code (ILColorPickerView.m and ILHuePickerView)... can, or have you, looked at his code (from the link above)?  It might make more sense to you.  BTW, I really appreciate your time helping me...

Comment: I think the best thing to do, if you can, is to zip the project folder up and email it to me.

Comment: ElJay... I got it working... it was a difference between XCode3 and XCode4... however, it takes the ENTIRE iPad scene... where do I start looking to make it smaller (like the size of the iPhone)?